# Cassandra Table to Spark Mapping in DataStax

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax

I am trying to use scala case class to map Cassandra table.

Some of my column names happen to be reserved key words in scala. Is there an easy way to map them ?

eg:

```
Cassandra Table
Create Table cars (
 id_uuid uuid,
 new boolean,
 type text,
 PRIMARY KEY ((id_uuid))
)

// This declaration will fail as "new" and "type" are reserved keywords
scala> case class Cars (idUuid : String, new : Boolean, type: String)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
case class Cars (idUuid:String, `new`:Boolean, `type`:String)
```

Comment: If possible, avoid using Cassandra keywords, and mixed case names for columns if you intend to use SparkSQL. It fails in funky ways. [Your column names are fine if you don't need quotes for querying in dev center.]